# .NET Regex replace chars inside group

Tags: .net, regex, replace

I'm using a regular expression replace (in a .Net application) to create an item id from a barcode. Here's the regex I'm using:

```
^(?<Bestellnr>\w{6})(?<Pos>\d{3})M(?<Menge>\d{5})P(?<Lfd>\d{3})$
```

The replacement string is (it has leading blanks, but that's not important here):

```
${Bestellnr}${Pos} ${Lfd}
```

An example input would be:

```
685774010M00555P002
```

The current result of the above replacement is:

```
685774010 002
```

But now my customer wants me to remove the leading zeroes from the groups "Pos" and "Lfd", so the result should change to:

```
685774 10   2
```

Edit: Please note that the *two* zeroes in the "lfd" group are replaced by *two* blanks!

I've tried for hours now, but I cannot seem to get this working. Best approach I was able to find was to create extra groups for the leading zeroes like:

```
^(?<Bestellnr>\w{6})(?<PosNull>0*)(?<Pos>\d{1,})M(?<Menge>\d{5})P(?<LfdNull>0*)(?<Lfd>\d{1,})$
```

But I don't know how I can replace the "null groups" with the correct number of blanks. Is this possible at all? (Until now I thought there's nothing that's not possible with Regex ;-)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution that fits my needs. It's done with a simple String.Format, passing it the Groups of the Regex converted to ints. Groups are accessed by index, but since it's done in the format string, no hardcoding is required.

Here's the code:

```
// both from app.config
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Bestellnr>\w{6})(?<Pos>\d{3})M(?<Menge>\d{5})P(?<Lfd>\d{3})");
string format = "   {0,6:d}{1,3:d} {3,3:d}";    

string barcode = "685774010M00555P002";

Match match = regex.Match(barcode);
if (match.Success)
{
    var groups = (from Group grp in match.Groups select grp.Value).Skip(1).Select(x => (object)int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
    string s = string.Format(format, groups);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Remarks:

- Skip(1) is necessary because the first group in the collection is the complete match itself.
- the cast to object is required because string.format needs a params object[] array and won't work with int[]

Comment: @garyh I will as soon as it's possible (20hours from now). Thanks for your help nevertheless!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
string input = "685774010M00555P002";

input = Regex.Replace(input, 
    @"^(?<Bestellnr>\w{6})0*(?<Pos>\d{1,3})M(?<Menge>\d{5})P0*(?<Lfd>\d{1,3})$", 
    m => m.Groups["Bestellnr"].Value + 
         m.Groups["Pos"].Value.PadLeft(3, ' ') + 
         m.Groups["Lfd"].Value.PadLeft(4, ' '));
```

result:

```
input = "685774 10   2"
```

**Edit:**
Kept the same regex as before but changed the replace

**Another Edit:**

You can remove the group names completely and refer to them by number:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, 
@"^(\w{6})0*(\d{1,3})M(\d{5})P0*(\d{1,3})$", 
m => m.Groups[1].Value + 
     m.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(3, ' ') + 
     m.Groups[4].Value.PadLeft(4, ' '));
```

Note: `m.Groups[0]` refers to the entire match

Comment: Thanks gary, but I'd need to replace two leading zeroes with *two* blanks (and three zeroes with three blanks and so on...)

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll have another think.

Comment: As @Some1.Kill.The.DJ stated you'll need to use a delegate in the replace - just use `string.PadLeft()` to pad out the spaces

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by replacing 0's with space using `matchevaluator`!

```
Regex.Replace("685774010M00555P002",
@"^(?<Bestellnr>\w{6})(?<Pos>\d{3})M(?<Menge>\d{5})P(?<Lfd>\d{3})$",
m=>m.Groups["Bestellnr"].Value+""+
   Regex.Replace(m.Groups["Pos"].Value,"(?<=^0*)0"," ")+
   " "+
   Regex.Replace(m.Groups["Lfd"].Value,"(?<=^0*)0"," "));
```

Comment: Thanks Some1, but I'd prefer a solution with a "pure" replace (so I won't have to change code but just the regex, which is configurable)

Comment: @Abagneele that is not possible with only regex...you have to use delegate for it..there is `no other way`..

Comment: Answering both Some1.Kill.The.DJ and @GaryH here as their answers are practically the same: Ok, technically that's an easy solution. But what I don't like about that is that I'll have to reference the named groups inside my code. Now if the customer decides to change the group names (for whatever reason, remember it's configurable), I'll have a problem.
Can this be done more elegantly (by means of not referencing names that I'll have no control about)?

Comment: you can refer to those groups with numbers like `$1` for `Bestellnr` group and so on

Comment: Yes, but then I would depend on the *order* of groups, which doesn't make it much better (or even worse...)

Comment: @Abagneele so basically you are saying that the input string can be in different forms..and if it can be in different forms edit the question and specify all the valid forms so that we can help you

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Yes, the input string can be in different forms, but that's not the point here. The point *is* that the regular expression as well as the replacement string come from app.config so the user can customize it to his needs. So I do not want to hardcode group names (or indexes). That's why I tried to do it all with a simple Regex.Replace().